# Need regex for url pattern

Tags: regex

i need a regex that validate this urls:

Bad:

```
www.*.com

www.abc*

*.*
```

Good:

```
*abc.com
*.com
www.abc.com
```

Comment: Have you tried by yourself? Could you post your solution?

Comment: It is not difficult to find an answer on Google

Comment: i tried several times, but i can only validate one at time.

Comment: I have this, but not work....

[\w-*]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;/~+#-])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex like:

```
^(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+?)(\.com)$
```

Here's a breakdown of how the regex works:

> `^` matches the begining of the string
>
> `(www\.)?` checks for either nothing, or the string `www.` literally.
>
> `[a-zA-Z0-9\-]` matches any letter (capital and lowercase), as well as numbers and a the hyphen.
>
> `([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+?)` matches the above one or more times, and tries to find the smallest match.
>
> `(\.com)` matches the string `.com` literally.
>
> `$` matches the end of the string.

[Here's a live preview of the regex in action](https://regex101.com/r/kC7wG5/3) on regex101.com

This will allow URLs like:

- www.google.com
- www.apple.com
- jojodmo.com
- stackoverflow.com
- 99-FAKE-websites.com

But will not allow URLs like:

- mail.google.com
- data.stackexchange.com
- microsoft.net
- redirect.affiliate.scam.hop.clickbank.gov

If you would like to allow subdomains other than `www` (and more than one of them), as well as allow tlds other than `.com`, like above, you could use:

```
^(([\w\-]+\.)+?)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+?)(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})$
```

This changes:

> `(www\.)?` is changed to `(([\w\-]+\.)+?)?`.
>
> - `[\w\-]+` matches any letter (capital or lowercase), as well as numbers, hyphens, and underscores one or more times.
> - `\.` matches the character `.` literally.
> - `([\w\-]+\.)`**`+?`** matches the above one or more times, finding the smallest match.
> - `(([\w\-]+\.)+?)`**`?`** makes the above optional
>
> `(\.com)` is changed to `(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})`
>
> - `\.` matches the character `.` literally
> - `[a-zA-Z]{2,}` matches any letter, capital or lowercase, two or more times

If you would also like to add the above [here's a preview of the new regex](https://regex101.com/r/uF3iN6/3) on regex101.com.